# Yodlee JAVA REST client SDK

Tags: yodlee

Does yodlee provide packages like com.yodlee.soap.core.*  used in JAVA Sample SampleApp for REST or we will have to create our implementation for REST?

Comment: The best you get with REST in that sense is things like https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ that attempt to auto-deserialize JSON into classes. As REST does not have a WSDL-style spec standard, only WCF-backed REST could aim to achieve something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee doesn't provide any such package for REST. You will have to create your own implementation.